# Ballerina CLASS_NOT_FOUND exception

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I followed https://github.com/wso2-ballerina/module-ftp and tried to run a sample file as follows

```
ballerina run getFtp.bal
```

It gives me following output

```
Compiling source
        getFtp.bal
error: wso2:ftp:/src/ftp/external_functions.bal:70:1: {ballerinax/java}CLASS_NOT_FOUND message=org.wso2.ei.b7a.ftp.core.client.FTPClient
error: wso2:ftp:/src/ftp/external_functions.bal:75:1: {ballerinax/java}CLASS_NOT_FOUND message=org.wso2.ei.b7a.ftp.core.server.FTPListenerHelper
```

Note that I ran `ballerina pull wso2/ftp` command prior to this, Is there anything else to do, any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you check which version of wso2/ftp you have ? You can find the version in `<USER_HOME>/.ballerina/balo_cache/wso2/ftp/` folder.

Comment: What is your ballerina version ? Can you check with ballerina 1.0.3 ?

Comment: Could you try running your ballerina project using the module name, as `ballerina run module_name`, and see if the error persists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue where interoperability did not work for single ballerina files. That is why you are getting this error. Try converting your code to a project module. Then it will work with the ballerina version you have.

This issue is fixed in ballerina 1.0.3 (https://ballerina.io/downloads/).

Comment: Hi hYk it worked with 1.0.3 thanks for the quick response

Comment: BTW does ballerina support SFTP When I tried to connect to a sftp host it gives me this error: org.wso2.ei.b7a.ftp.core.util.BallerinaFTPException message=Unable to initialize the FTP listener: Failed to initialize File server connector for Service: ftpServerConnector$$service$0 cause=error org.wso2.transport.remotefilesystem.exception.RemoteFileSystemConnectorException message=Failed to initialize File server connector for Service: ftpServerConnector$$service$0

Comment: FTP Module supports connecting via SFTP as well. Could you check if the protocol is set to `ftp:SFTP` and the port is set to `22`, along with the username and password details? These details have to be modified in both `ftp:Listener` and `ftp:ClientEndpointConfig` configs.

Comment: In addition to the above, the `path` config for the listening folder should be the home directory for the SFTP user. For instance, if you have `/home/sftpdir` and SFTP user has access only to the `sftpdir` directory, the path config should be `path: "/sftpdir"`. All directory paths also should start from this directory.